# What is the difference between a website and a virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, virtual-directory

What is the difference between a website and a virtual directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're comparing Red Delicious apples to Granny Smiths.

A [website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972) is an application served over the internet using the HTTP protocol, primarily consisting of pages holding different types of content (text, images, videos, etc).

A [virtual directory](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-apps-and-vdirs-in-iis-7/) is a way that IIS maps a directory on your hard drive to a website.  The virtual directory becomes part of the URL.  For instance, if you have a web server

> www.c_ntoso.com

and it has a virtual directory

> foo

that maps to

> c:\foo\

on the web server, you can see the web page

> c:\foo\bar.html

via the url

> www.c_ntoso.com/foo/bar.htm